# Why is my function not returning the correct value in seconds?

Tags: c#, .net

How come that s returns `7942` when it should be 13 minutes aka roughly `780` seconds?

```cs
var s = Math.Round((DateTime.Now - FromUnixTime(1589414482)).TotalSeconds);

DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime FromUnixTime(long unixTime)
{
    return epoch.AddSeconds(unixTime);
}
```

Comment: timezones. epoch times are utc. `DateTime.Now` is a local time.

Comment: There we go! Thank you!

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow will return UTC current time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DateTime.Now` returns a local time. Unix Epoch times are based on UTC. That's your difference.